# How To Open New Window With PDF File When You Click a Toggle Switch On

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to open new webpage with pdf when you click a toggle switch.But it did not open and i tried my best.please tell me how to do it. for example i want to open css pdf when you a click a toggle switch on then when you off a toggle switch then pdf window will be close.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsClassName('switch').addEventListener("change",function(){
if (this.checked) window.open("PDFS/CSS.pdf");
});
</script>
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
</style>
<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>
```

Comment: I guess your change event isn't firing. Try something like `click`.

Comment: i tried with onchange event it did not also work.How can i do that bro.

Comment: Did you already try `click`?

Comment: I tried as a onclick = click(); function in javascript code

Comment: Try `addEventListener('click', function()...` instead of `addEventListener('change', function()...`.

Comment: Please tell  me frnds it is usefull for me  if it will execute.

Comment: The `change` event inside your `eventListener` should work. Did you try it?

Comment: I tried click and change events bro if you have any code regarding this send me

Comment: And what happend when you tried `click` or anyting else? Any errors in your JavaScript console? (press F12, then head to "console")

Comment: it shows document.getElementsByClassName(..).addEventListener(...) is not function

Comment: Ah, I didn't see an issue all the time. Add `[0]` after `getElementsByClassName('switch')`.

Comment: I am doing in netbeans because here no internet for installing react.this is a central govt

Comment: Ok. Did you add `[0]`? Did it work?

Comment: I done in JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a simple solution for you. Do it in Jquery.

change your div from:

```
<div class="slider"></div>
```

To:

```
<div class="slider" id="slider"></div>
```

And in your script delete your code and put this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider').click(function(){
        window.open('CSS.pdf', '_blank', 'fullscreen=yes'); 
    });

});
```

P.S - don't forget to add the jquery extension and in css.pdf put your pdf name file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: jQuery isn't a solution to everything and I think it's overkill for this simple task. Also, OP is stuck at this simple task, so introducing a library to them might confuse them even more. They should learn JS to a solid level first.

Comment: Also, adding an ID to the element and getting the element by said ID would work with plain JS very well too.